# Most general concept of tensor product

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, tensor-products

Inspired by the definition of tensor products of vector spaces, I have been thinking about what sorts of algebraic sets admit tensor products. Also, I don't know much category theory, but am quite interested in the subject.

I have been thinking of a following generalization:

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a category, let $\text{Ob}(\mathcal{C})$ be the collection of objects of $\mathcal{C}$ and let $\text{Mor}(\mathcal{C})$ be the collection of morphisms of $\mathcal{C}$.

Let $X_1,...,X_k,Y\in\text{Ob}(C)$ be objects. I will call a map $\phi:X_1\times...\times X_k\rightarrow Y$ a multimorphism, if $\phi_i\in\text{Mor}(\mathcal{C})$ if $\phi_i$ is considered a map $\phi: X_i\rightarrow Y$ where all other arguments are held fixed.

Let $Z$ also be an object, and let $p:X_1\times...\times X_k\rightarrow Z$ be a multimorphism. The pair $(Z,p)$ is the tensor product of the objects $X_1,...,X_k$ if for any multimorphism $\phi:X_1\times...\times X_k\rightarrow Y$ there exists a unique morphism $\phi^\otimes:Z\rightarrow Y$ such that $\phi=\phi^\otimes\circ p$.

- Is this construction meaningful in the sense that it exists irrespective of what $\mathcal{C}$ is?
- If this construction is meaningful, then does this construction automatically guarantee that the tensor product is unique (in some sense I do not know)?
- Is this construction interesting to anyone, or I am just being overeager?

Comment: Maybe [monoïdal closed categories](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/closed+monoidal+category) could be of interest to you. As for your generalization, it's not really clear what "all other arguments are held fixed" should mean in an arbitrary category.

Comment: Also, what is $X_1\times X_2$ in an arbitrary category? And why not in stead start with objects $X_1,...,X_k,Y\in\text{Ob}(C)$ and then *take* morphisms $\phi_i\in\text{Mor}_{\mathcal{C}}(X_i,Y)$, and call the collection $\{\phi_i\}$ a multimorphism?

Comment: Aside, this construction is very similar to the usual definition of the tensor product in terms of its universal property. Existence is not ensured in general, but the unique morphism $\phi^{\otimes}$ ensures that if there exist two tensor products of a multimorphism, then there is a *unique* isomorphism between them that preserves the universal property (i.e. the existence of a unique morphism $\phi^{\otimes}$).

Comment: I think you have in mind not a category, but a *concrete category*: a category with a faithful functor $U : \mathcal{C} \to \mathbf{Set}$, and many of the things you are talking about don't take place in $\mathcal{C}$ at all. e.g. I think you mean a multimorphism to be a arrow of set $\phi : UX_1 \times \ldots \times UX_k \to UY$.

Comment: Your initial definition makes me think you're about to rediscover (representable) [multicategories](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/multicategory)

Answer (score 1):

It was already commented that this concept makes sense for *concrete* categories. This has been studied in the following article (also have a look at [the articles which cite it](https://scholar.google.de/scholar?cites=12393492188586675223&as_sdt=2005&sciodt=0,5&hl=de)):

> B. Banaschewski and E. Nelson. Tensor products and bimorphisms. Can. Math. Bull. 19 (1976), 385-402